# If convex (hyperbolic) $\square ABCD$ has right angles at $A$, $B$, $D$, then $|AD| < |BC|$.

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

> Assume convex (hyperbolic) quadrilateral $\square ABCD$ has right angles at $A$, $B$, and $D$. Let $x = |AD|$ and $y =|BC|$. Prove $x < y$.

I know that the sum of the angles is less than $360^\circ$. Yet, other than the scalene inequality for triangles, I don't know how to best relate two sides together. I thought of trying by contradiction, but I didn't see any major contradiction that would happen if $y \geq x$.

Comment: Why would sum of angles be less than 360 if this quadrilateral is convex?

Comment: Is this a convex quadrilateral or a quadrilateral in curved geometry?

Comment: A convex quadrilateral, also less then 360 since triangles are less then 180 in neutral geometry

Comment: The sum of the angles of a triangle in neutral geometry is at most 180. For your particular problem, if we assume less than 180, we are talking hyperbolic geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is in hyperbolic geometry, this property can help you. Line AD is a unique line that joins two ultraparallel lines formed by the extensions of AB and DC and is perpendicular to both of them. It is also the closest distance between the two lines. That is, any other line between the AB and DC will be longer.

Comment: How is it the closest distance between the two lines? How could you show that $BC$ is between $AB$ and $DC$?

Comment: Look up the ultraparallel theorem in hyperbolic geometry. It describes the unique line between two ultraparallel lines being perpendicular to both. The ultra parallel lines diverge either side of this unique line. To your other question, BC shares a common point with AB and DC.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C^\prime$ be a point on $\overrightarrow{BC}$ such that $|AD|=|BC^\prime|$. Then (as per the Claim in [my answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2744035/409)), $\square ABC^\prime D$ has congruent angles at $D$ and $C^\prime$. These congruent angles must each be smaller than a right angle; in particular, $\angle ADC^\prime < 90^\circ = \angle ADC$, so that $C^\prime$ is in the interior of $\angle ADC$ and thus lies somewhere between $B$ and $C$. $\square$